# Discord py await seems to halt other asynchronous commands when I don't want it to

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, discord, python-multithreading

so I'm writing a discord bot using discord.py. So far I have -play command which adds song to queue. and -queue which displays the queue. This part of the play function seems to be the problem`with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl: meta=ydl.extract_info(url,download=False) url2=meta['formats'][0]['url'] source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2,**FFMPEG_OPTIONS)` -queue responds well within seconds if there is nothing downloading but if I spam queue a bunch of songs, -queue will only output anything after ALL of the sources have been made even though it's another function entirely. Why is this halting the other functions if they are asynchronous? Do I need to create a thread instead?

Comment: Afaik discord.py itself is fine, youtube_dl is the culprit since it fetches YouTube info synchronously (the `extract_info` part)

Comment: I tried with pafy and it still does the same thing. The extract_info is asynchronous because it doesn't slow down all the other commands when I remove the line awaiting